# MySQL - Showing blog archives: March 2012, April 2012, May 2012

Tags: mysql, sql

I have built a blog and now want to show a list of archive blog posts by month and year, but with counts, like this:

```
January 2012  ---  1,054
February 2012 ---  403
March 2012 ------  972
April 2012 ------  103
...
```

I have a table called "blog_articles" containing these primary fields:

```
article_id  INT
published   DATETIME
```

What is the best way to do this? Should I use my server-side language (VBScript/ASP) to loop through the months making a separate SQL count query for each one or should I do all of this is MySQL? If you say all in MySQL, could you suggest something to help me on my way.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this query then loop through the record set

```
Select CONCAT( MONTHNAME(published) , ' ' , YEAR(published)) as monthyear, count(*) from blog_articles GROUP by CONCAT( MONTHNAME(published) , ' ' , YEAR(published))
```

Comment: WOW, that's bang on! Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

Try this::

Select CONCAT( MONTH(published) , ' ' , YEAR(published)) as monthyear, count(*) from blog_articles GROUP by YEAR(published), MONTH(published)